# Wait/Pause/Sleep in jQuery Each Loop between Iterations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I simply want to add a pause after each iteration of a jQuery each loop, I can't seem to figure it out.

```
$(".item").each(function(i){
    var el = this;
    var timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $(el).trigger("click");
    }, 500);
});
```

This is not firing every 1/2 second, but rather triggering click on all items at once.

I want something like this (pseudocode):

```
$(".item").each(function(i){
    $(this).trigger("click");
    wait(500); // wait a half second before the next iteration
});
```

Any working method of this?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot really do this with `$.each`. You can use `setTimeout` and keep a reference to the index you are currently at:

```
function process(elements, cb, timeout) {
    var i = 0;
    var l = elements.length;

    (function fn() {
        cb.call(elements[i++]);
        if (i < l) {
            setTimeout(fn, timeout);
        }
    }());
}

process($('.item'), function() {
    $(this).click();
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this or you can write your a SetTimeOut function which you already tried

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Yq2SL/2/ : you will see different parent of div with `class=item`

API: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.dequeue/ & http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/#jQuery-queue1

Few sources for your reading:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/delay-and-click-issue

http://blog.project-sierra.de/archives/1559

**Sample code:**

```
$(".item").delay(500).queue(function(){ 
  $(this).trigger("click"); 
  $(this).dequeue(); 
});
```